# Where does Microsoft Cluster Service store its cluste resource settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-cluster-server

Windows Server 2008 Cluster Service appears to store settings for its resources somewhere that allow them to travel from node to node. Where is that information stored?

Answer (score 1):

On the Quorum disk, in the 'Cluster' folder.

MSDN has a very nice article describing how it works: [Understanding Quorum in a Failover Cluster](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2011/05/27/10169261.aspx)

Comment: How does my second node access the quorum disk when the current owner of the quorum group is the first node?